# Minimum Android API version for App

Tags: android

I am new to Android development and had a question on what should be the minimum Android version to pick for an app (phones only, not tablet) that is intended for the USA market.

I have been looking at this (https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) and thinking may be API 10(Gingerbread) is the way to go. However some folks have suggested that I can safely pick API 15(Ice Cream Sandwich) and I should be fine.

What are other app developers doing?

Comment: If you are starting a brand new app, it is pretty pointless to make one that targets anything less then ICS API 14

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio has it defaulted to ICS (API 15), which will get you 100% of tablets.

This [table](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) shows that API 15 would get you 85.8% of all Android Devices currently being used.

The problem is that some of the APIs use methods that are preferred over the older APIs and you will run into a lot of times where you need to handle one way for an older API level, and a second way for a newer API. So you have a lot of potential for if < API 16 do x, else do y.

So you need to weigh the maintenance cost vs what percent of the market you want to capture.  Personally, I chose API 16 because the 11% of tablets created more work to maintain API 15 then benefit of having that user base.